# PHP loop split by 4

Tags: php, html, loops

How would I achieve this PHP task?

I have an unordered html list and and array. 
My code adds list tags to each item in the array to create one big unordered list

```
            <ul>
                 <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
                        <li><?php print $row ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

current output below

```
            <ul>
                <li>01</li>
                <li>02</li>
                <li>.....</li>
                <li>.....</li>
                <li>15</li>
            </ul>
```

What I want is to split the list items so that they are in groups of 4 as sub unordered lists. If the number is not divisible by 4 then the remainder should be a smaller list at the end, for example.

```
            <ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>01</li>
                    <li>02</li>
                    <li>.....</li>
                    <li>.....</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>05</li>
                    <li>06</li>
                    <li>.....</li>
                    <li>.....</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>09</li>
                    <li>10</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you loop maintain a counter, when the counter reach to a value which provide a mod 0 you draw a `</ul><ul>` and also a starting `<ul>` and a ending `</ul>` at the beginning and end of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this is the solution I went for. This solution includes a statement to close the tags if there are a number of items not divisible by four, for example if there are five items in total. Thanks to everyone, I couldn't have done it without your input.

```
            $count;
            foreach ($rows as $id => $row)
                {
                    if ($count % 4 == 0)
                    {           
                        echo "<ul>";
                    }

                    echo '<li>' . $row . '</li>';

                    if ($count % 4 == 3 || $count == count($rows)-1)
                    {
                        echo "</ul>";
                    }
                    $count++;
                }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
    <?php if ($id > 0 && $id % 4 === 0): ?>
        </ul><ul>
    <?php endif ;?>
    <li><?php echo $row; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

(Note that if the key of your `$rows` array is not simply an index number, you'll need to maintain your own counter variable.)

Comment: Thanks very much. See my final code below. I have included a statement to close the tags at the end of the list, regardless if it is divisible by four or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$id=0;
foreach ($rows as $id => $row)
{
    $id+=1;
    if ($id % 4 == 0)
    {
         echo "<ul>";
    }

    echo "<li>$i</li>";

    if ($id % 4 == 0)
    {
         echo "</ul>";
    }
}

if ($id % 4 != 0)
{
    echo "</ul>";
}    
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. Much appreciated. I went with this solution in the end as the array may change to an associative array later.

Comment: @n00b13: note that this solution (also) will not work if the array is associative: the `foreach` will overwrite `$id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
  if ($id % 4 == 0) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
   <?php
                 $rows = array("2","3","5","6","8","9","0","3","5");
                 $i =0;
                  foreach ($rows as $id => $row): 
                  if($i % 4 == 0)
                  { echo "</ul><ul>";}
                  $i++;
                  ?>
                        <li><?php print $row ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```