# BOOTSTRAP Looping checkbox

Tags: php, loops, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with looping checkbox bootstrap from result_array()
this the pics [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgrnh.png)
and this the code

```html
<?php if ($bn) : ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($bn as $a) : ?>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="1" name="1" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="1">Data</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

my data in database 5 record

how to get data like that result_array() 
be like [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzQ3C.png)

I mean if looping has been done 4 times. make a new row. so each row is filled with 4 columns

Comment: Im not sure what you mean with bootstrap, but I think you just want a new line after every fourth item in your array. So you could split up your array in sub arrays and itrerate over them.

Comment: Or just do it like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252479/php-loop-split-by-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want the 5th checkbox to be at the bottom? if so why not replace:

```
    <div class="col">
```

with

```
<div class="col-3 mb-3">
```

?

Comment: nope bro. I mean if looping has been done 4 times. make a new row. so each row is filled with 4 columns

Comment: oh so it has to be a new row?

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap grid system is divided in 12 col space total.

You can change the class of the div to `<div class="col-3">` which will put 4 cols(4*3 = 12) in the first row and the 5th col in a second row.